# How to add partition using hive by a specific date?

Tags: hadoop, amazon-s3, hive

I'm using hive (with external tables) to process data stored on amazon S3.

My data is partitioned as follows:

```
                       DIR   s3://test.com/2014-03-01/
                       DIR   s3://test.com/2014-03-02/
                       DIR   s3://test.com/2014-03-03/
                       DIR   s3://test.com/2014-03-04/
                       DIR   s3://test.com/2014-03-05/

s3://test.com/2014-03-05/ip-foo-request-2014-03-05_04-20_00-49.log
s3://test.com/2014-03-05/ip-foo-request-2014-03-05_06-26_19-56.log
s3://test.com/2014-03-05/ip-foo-request-2014-03-05_15-20_12-53.log
s3://test.com/2014-03-05/ip-foo-request-2014-03-05_22-54_27-19.log
```

How to create a partition table using hive?

```
   CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE test (
    foo string,
    time string,
    bar string
    )  PARTITIONED BY (? string)
    ROW FORMAT DELIMITED
    FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t'
    LOCATION 's3://test.com/';
```

Could somebody answer this question ? Thanks!

Answer (score 48, accepted):

First start with the right table definition. In your case I'll just use what you wrote:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE test (
    foo string,
    time string,
    bar string
)  PARTITIONED BY (dt string)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t'
LOCATION 's3://test.com/';
```

Hive by default expects partitions to be in subdirectories named via the convention s3://test.com/partitionkey=partitionvalue. For example

```
s3://test.com/dt=2014-03-05
```

If you follow this convention you can use MSCK to add all partitions.

If you can't or don't want to use this naming convention, you will need to add all partitions as in:

```
ALTER TABLE test
    ADD PARTITION (dt='2014-03-05')
    location 's3://test.com/2014-03-05'
```

Comment: The above query is working without any syntactic error. But doesn't load any data. output is 0 bytes. Can u help me?

Comment: ALTER TABLE px_logs ADD PARTITION (ds=date_sub('${DAY}', 1)); When i'm trying to use python code for get current date also got error: FAILED: Parse Error: line 3:38 cannot recognize input 'date_sub' in constant

Comment: @brisk I got the same problem, nothing loaded, the metastore show me the localtion still has dt= style, which is not we set in ALTER. Do you get any idea now?

Comment: Use `MSCK REPAIR TABLE table_name;` after the files are there in the mentioned partition format for the partitions to be auto added in one go!

Comment: @carter-shanklin, can you elaborate on the use of MSCK in this context?  Also, I search the web to novail and cannot find any reference to the convention you are speaking.  Can you provide any references?

Answer (score 4):

If you are going to partition using date field you need s3 folder structure as mentioned below:

```
s3://test.com/date=2014-03-05/ip-foo-request-2014-03-05_04-20_00-49.log
```

In such case you can create external table with partition column as **date** 
and run `MSCK REPAIR TABLE EXTERNAL_TABLE_NAME` to update hive meta store.

Comment: CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE test (
    foo string,
    time string,
    bar string
    )  PARTITIONED BY (date string)
    ROW FORMAT DELIMITED
    FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t'
    LOCATION 3://test.com/';  MSCK REPAIR TABLE test; I ran this script. It's does not load datas from s3.. In the given above s3 path have many log files are there.. How to use the MSCK REPAIR TABLE?.

Comment: Can you post the output from your s3 folder

Answer (score 4):

If you have existing directory structure that doesn't comply `<partition name>=<partition value>`, you have to add partitions manually. MSCK REPAIR TABLE won't work unless you structure your directory like so.

After you specify location on table creation like:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE test (
    foo string,
    time string,
    bar string
)  
PARTITIONED BY (dt string)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t'
LOCATION 's3://test.com/';
```

You can add partition without specifying full path:

```
ALTER TABLE test ADD PARTITION (dt='2014-03-05') LOCATION '2014-03-05';
```

Although I've never checked it, I suggest you to move your partitions into a folder inside the bucket, not directly in the bucket itself. E.g. from `s3://test.com/` to `s3://test.com/data/`.

Answer (score 2):

Please look at the response posted above by Carter Shanklin.  You need to make sure your files are stored in the directory structure as partitionkey=partitionvalue i.e. Hive by default expects partitions to be in subdirectories named via the convention.

In your example it should be stored as

s3://test.com/date=20140305/ip-foo-request-2014-03-05_04-20_00-49.log.

Steps to be followed:

i) Make sure data exists in the above structure
ii) Create the external table 
iii) Now run the msck repair table.

Answer (score 1):

I think the the data is present in the s3 location and might not updated in the metadata, (emrfs). In order this to work first do emrfs import and emrfs sync.
And then apply the msck repair.

It will add all the partitions that are present in s3